# Redirect from default controller to HMVC modules controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

How to redirect from CI default controller to HMVC modules controller?

I have a fresh installation of CI, in which I have defined default controller in ***/application/config/routes.php***

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```

Now I am trying to use complete modular way and write everything in modules directory. For that purpose I have created a home app in

***/application/modules/home/controllers/Home.php***

Now the issue I am having is, I am not able to directly redirect to my home page using ***localhost/ci***

This url is redirecting to default welcome.php

When I pass ***localhost/ci/index.php/home*** I can navigate to home page.

I tried using redirect, it didn't work.

I want to redirect to home page using ***localhost/ci*** url. Please help.

Comment: Can some one please let me know, why my question got downvote? Isn't it as per SO standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your default controller like this..

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

if you want to redirect to particular method of your controller:Then

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/method_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';`

to

`$route['default_controller'] = 'folder_name/controller_name';`

in your routes file.

and try

Comment: what is your folder structure ? it should be "modules/folder_name/controllers/controller_name.php" . if you want run any specific method, then write that method after controller_name, otherwise just folder_name/controller_name(it runs index() function of that controller).

Comment: Ok, you mean to say folder name is not modules, it should be actual app name. I got it. It works. I thought folder_name refers to the name of modules folder. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Ganesh Aher no need to give `modules` folder name.HMVC by default takes all the controllers from folders.